# minitest errors not showing up when I run rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have been working on debugging my app for a few hours now. I type `rake test` to get a report on my errors. For no reason apparent to me, all of a sudden the output of `rake test` is

```
Run options: --seed 33507

# Running:

........................EEEEEEE...........................E...........E.E.EF..EE...............................F.......F..EE....................FEEE..............................................
```

Only minutes earlier this command showed me the result of each test. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the complete output? Did the test detected an endless loop in this test sequence? Or did the test finish?

Comment: yes this is the complete output. The test _appeared_ to finished based on the fact that I get a new command prompt.

Comment: Ok, it was just the idea of a endless loop with this specific test sequence. But when your test finish it must be another reason.

Comment: I did and that fixed it! Good catch! If you want to submit this as a solution I will gladly approve it.

Comment: Interesting - I removed my question in my comment because a test showed, that an exit should make no difference. I will try to make example to get the same result as you.

Comment: I had a line that looked something like this `exit = ProgramExit.new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a `exit`in the code.
The `exit` stops the execution before the test results are written.

A minimal example to repeat the problem:

```
class MyTest < MiniTest::Test
  @@x = 0
  def test_true
    @@x += 1
    assert true
  end
  def test_exit
     exit 0 if @@x > 0
   end
  def test_false
    assert false
  end
end
```

Depending on the sequence order you get different results:

```
Run options: --seed 21072

# Running:

F..

Finished in 0.001011s, 2967.6086 runs/s, 1978.4057 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
MyTest#test_false [test.rb:13]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

3 runs, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Or another result:

```
Run options: --seed 10907

# Running:

F.
```

Background: Minitest executes the tests in random order. With the seed you can repeat your test in the same sequence.

In my example `--seed 10907` executes first `test_true`, then `test_exit` with the executed `exit`-statement - and the output is lost.

With `--seed 21072` the `test_exit` is executed before `test_true` and the `exit`is not executed. You get the result.